# g++, c4droid and picking up includes

Tags: android, c++

I'm trying to run through some SVG files using the TinyXML source code.

At home I have this set up fine.

But being away from the computer a lot I moved the files to my Android phone to do some coding via c4droid and the g++ plugin. My phone isn't rooted but the plugin is installed internally (and yes I have chosen the correct plugin from the prefs).

The problem is is that it cannot find anything, for example the TinyXML source code. The error message consists of a long list of class method names prepended with "undefined reference to..." and are from a file called temp.c

The includes are defined like this...

```
#include "tinyxml/tinyxml.h"
```

where the folder tinyxml is in the same directory as the file main.cpp with the main function

I have an inkling it's trying to find the source and headers relative to the temp directory but I'm probably completely wrong, I'm not that familiar with g++ and its error messages.

Any help on how g++ or c4droid in general picks up includes is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, i know the thread is old, but anyway: Another and more simple solution is to hold down the "Compile" button and add all your source files with the option "Compile multiple source code files (simple)". It will take basis in the file that has main defined.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if this is a feature implemented recently or I didn't quite understand how to use the app at the time but this has worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know that with G++ you can compile thus:

g++ [-flags] example.out -o example.cpp include1.cpp include1.h

which produces the executable `example.out` where `example.cpp` has `int main()` and includes `include1.h`'s code.

I am myself however struggling to include files using G++ + Bionic within C4Droid. I have had luck when modifying the NativeActivity example that comes with the GCC plugin for the C4Droid app.

Apologies I can't help more - I see it's been a year now!

Edit: I found a solution to our problem: I hope this helps any others astray with C4Droid in time to come - great app!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385047/android-to-ubuntu-tcip-ip-in-c-compiled-with-c4droid-bionic-libc-a-general

Comment: Thank you, I wish I could tick both answers and I appreciate that a year later you found a reply. Thanks